# Probability question for multiple events

Tags: probability

If I have a system that may fail by one of two events.
The probability of the system to fail due to the first event is 3/5; whereas the probability of the system to fail by the second event is 4/5. what is the  probability of the system to fail?

I know that shall be 3/5 + 4/5 (I think) but I want the value to be less than 1

Answer (score 1):

There's some odd language here because technically we would need to know the probability of either event happening. But it sounds like we're assuming that each event did in fact happen. Then the probability of failure is 1 minus the chance of neither event causing failure:

$$1-(1-3/5)(1-4/5)$$

Comment: Actually, both events happened. For example, if a car failure may happen due to a failure of the engine or transmission or both together. We know that the probability of failure for engine is 3/5 and transmission probability of failure is 4/5. So still i can use the equation you provided? What if I have three evwnts also?

Answer (score 0):

Given the probabilities you mention, clearly the two events are not mutually exclusive. The addition rule you are using only applies to mutually exclusive events. For events that are not mutually exclusive, the rule is slightly modified:

P(A or B)=P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B).

Thus, it would be helpful to know (i) what the probability of the two events occurring simultaneously is, and (ii) are there any other possible outcomes (i.e., can the system not fail at all, or can it fail in scenarios other than the two events you mention?)